# Getting Error when trying to perform form validation with spring and thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm trying to perform form validation with spring and Thymeleaf, but when navigating to the form URL I am getting the following error:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error,
>   status=500). Error during execution of processor
>   'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor'
>   (template: "create-store-form" - line 18, col 28)

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/createStoreForm.html")
public ModelAndView getCreateStoreForm() {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("create-store-form");
    return modelAndView;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/submitNewStoreForm" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView submitNewStoreForm(@Valid @ModelAttribute("newStore") Store store, BindingResult bindingResult, HttpSession httpSession, Principal principal) {
    String loggedInUsername = principal.getName();
    User loggedInUser = userService.findUser(loggedInUsername);
    ModelAndView modelAndView;
    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        modelAndView = new ModelAndView("create-store-form");
        return modelAndView;
    }       
    try {
        store.setSellerName(loggedInUser.getUsername());
        storeService.saveStore(store);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        modelAndView = new ModelAndView("create-store-form");
        System.out.println("User '"+store.getName()+"' already exist on db.");
        bindingResult.addError(new ObjectError("dup", "* Store '"+store.getName()+"' already exist!"));
        return modelAndView;
    }
    modelAndView = new ModelAndView("store-page");
    modelAndView.addObject("storeName", store.getName());

    return modelAndView;

}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">

    <form action="#" th:action="@{/submitNewStoreForm}" th:object="${newStore}" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{name}" /></td>
            <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" th:errors="*{name}">Title error message</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Image Link:</td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{imageLink}" /></td>
            <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('imageLink')}" th:errors="*{imageLink}">Content error message</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><button type="submit">Submit post</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>


</div>
```

What am I doing wrong? I've followed [this guide](http://jvmhub.com/2015/08/02/spring-boot-with-thymeleaf-tutorial-part-2-forms-with-validation/).

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons for why this error might occur.

First try the following: In `getCreateStoreForm()`, replace

```
... = new ModelAndView("create-store-form”);
```

... with:

```
... = new ModelAndView("create-store-form”, “newStore”, new Store());
```

1. `"create-store-form”` = the html form view name
2. `“newStore”` = the object name (th:object in thymeleaf)
3. `new Store()` = a reference to the model object

Please let me know if this works. If it doesn’t, please post the full stack trace and the class for `Store`.